# Does using a lot of tail-recursion in Erlang slow it down?

Tags: erlang, tail-recursion

I've been reading about Erlang lately and how tail-recursion is so heavily used, due to the difficulty of using iterative loops.

Doesn't this high use of recursion slow it down, what with all the function calls and the effect they have on the stack? Or does the tail recursion negate most of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iterative tail recursion is generally implemented using [Tail calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).
This is basically a transformation of a recursive call to a simple loop.

C# example:

```
uint FactorialAccum(uint n, uint accum) {
    if(n < 2) return accum;
    return FactorialAccum(n - 1, n * accum);
};
uint Factorial(uint n) {
    return FactorialAccum(n, 1);
};
```

to

```
uint FactorialAccum(uint n, uint accum) {
start:
    if(n < 2) return accum;
    accum *= n;
    n -= 1;
goto start;
};
uint Factorial(uint n) {
    return FactorialAccum(n, 1);
};
```

or even better:

```
uint Factorial(uint n) {
    uint accum = 1;
start:
    if(n < 2) return accum;
    accum *= n;
    n -= 1;
goto start;
};
```

---

C# not real tail recursion, this is because the return value is modified, most compilers won't break this down into a loop:

```
int Power(int number, uint power) {
    if(power == 0) return 1;
    if(power == 1) return number;
    return number * Power(number, --power);
}
```

to

```
int Power(int number, uint power) {
    int result = number;
start:
    if(power == 0) return 1;
    if(power == 1) return number;
    result *= number;
    power--;
goto start;
}
```

Comment: Your first function is not tail recursive, so this will not but turned into iteration in Erlang.

Comment: You're basically right, but an good compiler should be able to see the structure. I'll modify my example later.

Comment: + Note that the last two actions before the jump back are directly derived from the tail call.

Comment: Added a real tail recursive example.

Comment: Nearly all compilers don't optimize the power function. I'm pretty sure Erlang doesn't, so don't depend on it!

Comment: Completely true. It would be an interesting project to write an precompiler to do this kind of things.

Answer (score 19):

The point is that Erlang optimizes tail calls (not only recursion).  Optimizing tail calls is quite simple:  if the return value is computed by a call to another function, then this other function is not just put on the function call stack on top of the calling function, but instead the stack frame of the current function is *replaced* by one of the called function.  This means that tail calls don't add to the stack size.

So, no, using tail recursion doesn't slow Erlang down, nor does it pose a risk of stack overflow.

With tail call optimization in place, you can not only use simple tail recursion, but also mutual tail recursion of several functions (a tail-calls b, which tail-calls c, which tail-calls a ...).  This can sometimes be a good model of computation.

Answer (score 3):

It should not affect performance in most cases. What you're looking for is not just tail calls, but tail call optimization (or tail call elimination). Tail call optimization is a compiler or runtime technique that figures out when a call to a function is the equivalent of 'popping the stack' to get back to the proper function instead of just returning. Generally tail call optimization of can only be done when the recursive call is the last operation in the function, so you have to be careful.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem pertaining to tail-recursion but it is not related to performance - Erlang tail-recursion optimisation also involves elimination of the stack trace for debugging.

For instance see Point 9.13 of the [Erlang FAQ](https://www.erlang.org/faq/problems.html#idm1129):

> Why doesn't the stack backtrace show the right functions for this code:
>
> ```erl
> -module(erl).
> -export([a/0]).
>
> a() -> b().
> b() -> c().
> c() -> 3 = 4.           %% will cause badmatch
> ```
>
> The stack backtrace only shows function c(), rather than a(), b() and c().
> This is because of last-call-optimisation; the compiler knows it does not need
> to generate a stack frame for a() or b() because the last thing it did was call another function, hence the stack frame does not appear in the stack backtrace.

This can be a bit of pain when you hit a crash (but it does kinda go with the territory of functional programming...)

Comment: Losing the stack's as annoying as debugging a stateful loop: you have no access to the state of the variables from the previous loop iteration. (In fact stateful loops and TCO have started to look equivalent to me.)

Answer (score 1):

A similar optimization that separates program text function calls from implementation function calls is 'inlining'.  In modern/thoughtful languages function calls have little relation to machine level function calls.